# Why do I get PROCEDURE does not exist when using callproc() in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I'm trying to use a stored procedure via a cursor and callproc() but I always get the error:

```
OperationalError: (1305, 'PROCEDURE myapp.LatLonDistance does not exist')
```

Here's the chunk of code that throws the error in my app:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.callproc("myapp.LatLonDistance", (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
cursor.close()
```

And here's a direct query that I can run on the DB that works just fine:

```
SELECT id,myapp.LatLonDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) AS distance FROM myapp.users_userprofile;
```

And here's the script I use to write the stored procedure to the DB:

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION airrun.LatLonDistance (lat1 double, lon1 double, lat2 double, lon2 double)
RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

        DECLARE theta double;
        DECLARE dist double;
        DECLARE miles double;
        SET theta = lon1 - lon2; 
        SET dist = SIN(RADIANS(lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat2)) + COS(RADIANS(lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(lat2)) * COS(RADIANS(theta)); 
        SET dist = ACOS(dist); 
        SET dist = DEGREES(dist); 
        SET miles = dist * 60 * 1.1515;


        RETURN miles;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Using a MySQL db. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it not the case that, whereas functions are SELECTed in MySQL, procedures are CALLed. The SQL above is a function, not a procedure?

Comment: That's entirely possible, I'm not much of a SQL guru.  What would be another way of achieving this then?

Comment: Rewrite this as a stored procedure. The CALL sytnax should then work. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that is a function, and not actually a stored procedure, you should be able to call it using `cursor.execute`:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.execute("SELECT id,myapp.LatLonDistance(%s, %s, %s, %s) AS distance FROM myapp.users_userprofile", (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
cursor.close()
```